# How to get the list of ntp servers on systemd

Tags: c, linux, systemd

I have a linux system with systemd 237. I need to get the list of NTP servers configured by DHCP using C code.

The sources of systemd has all the informations:

```
/* Get NTP entries for a given link. These are domain names or string
 * representations of IP addresses */
int sd_network_link_get_ntp(int ifindex, char ***ret);
```

(from sd-network.h)
But this interface isn't exposed in libsystemd.

I know that the latest systemd expose a dbus interface with the necessary informations, but I can't update it.

The /etc/ntp.conf isn't filled anymore.

The files under /run/systemd/netif aren't filled until networkctl is run and, even though, the files generated contains an explicit line at the start:

```
# This is private data. Do not parse.
```

If anyone has a solution.

Thank you

Comment: They added the dbus interface as a solution, presumably because there was no supported way to do it in the earlier version. If you can't upgrade, you have to do unsupported things, like parse the file that says not to parse it.

Comment: I think, i'll do with the output of the networkctl command, because, like i said, the contents of the files are only filled when it is launched.